# How to write an automatically sourced shell script to /etc/profile

Tags: bash, profile, etc

I heard through the grapevine that files in /etc/profile will be automatically sourced by bash upon login?

I tried writing something simple to /etc/profile:

```
 echo "echo 'foo'" > /etc/profile/foo.sh
```

but I got this weird error:

```
bash: /etc/profile/foo.sh: Not a directory
```

is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Don't listen to the grapevine. Look things up in your shell's manual instead. There, it may say that it sources `/etc/profile`, so have a look at that file. There, it may say that it's sourcing all the files in `/etc/profile.d`, or it may not, depending on your system. It certainly doesn't on my machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/etc/profile` is a file.  Hence the error when trying to create `/etc/profile/foo.sh`.

`/etc/profile.d` is the directory you're thinking of.  Scripts placed in there get sourced on login.  In your example, you'd want to create `/etc/profile.d/foo.sh`.

The script logic behind this and how it's pulled in can be seen below.  Similar code is in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `/etc/csh.login`.

```
$ grep -A 8 ^for.*profile.d /etc/profile
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
$
```

Example of creating and invoking such a script:

```
# echo id >/etc/profile.d/foo.sh
# su - steve
Last login: Sat Jun 23 21:44:41 UTC 2018 on pts/0
uid=1000(steve) gid=1001(steve) groups=1001(steve),4(adm),39(video),1000(google-sudoers) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$
```

More information at [What do the scripts in /etc/profile.d do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/what-do-the-scripts-in-etc-profile-d-do)

Comment: got it so `/etc/profile` sources the files in `/etc/profile.d` folder. Can you add an example of how to write a new file to `/etc/profile.d`? I am getting permissions issues. I assume sudo is needed, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Also, when /etc/profile.d files are run, I assume they are not run as root, but instead run as whoever is logging in?

Comment: Yes, root needed.  Otherwise some doofus could create a nasty script that got executed by anyone using the server.    When actually run, they run as whoever is logging in.

Comment: Ok thanks, frustratingly, if I run this `sudo echo "echo 'here here now.';" > /etc/profile.d/alex.sh`, I still get a permissions error. Weird.

Comment: `echo "echo 'here here now.'" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/alex.sh`

Comment: Hey Steve thanks, I guess that's how sudo works with `echo` specifically.

Comment: It's because the `sudo echo` itself gets elevated privileges, while subsequent stdout redirection remains running with *original* privileges.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "subsequent" redirection; the redirection is handled by the shell *before* `sudo` is even run.